# PyDev is acting stupid on python methods. # @UndefinedVariable

Tags: pydev

Since PyDev does not have a support page I will complain about it here.

Take for example the redis module and do the following method.

```
import redis 

pubsub = redis.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
```

PyDev then has no clue what pubsub you are talking about, an instance variable of redis, it's method or an instance of another class.

Is there a way to get PyDev to now which pubsub I'm talking about or is this an issue the PyDev team needs to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask PyDev to use a python shell to analyze **redis** or you can provide stubs for it.

See: **Forced Builtins** in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html to know how to ask it to analyze it through a shell and **Predefined Completions** in that same page to provide stubs.